# Уточнение “redirect” в kohane 3.3.5

Tags: php, kohana, framework

Исходя из http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading#redirects-http-300-301-302-303-307 функции “*Redirect*”, я
Написал:

```
$this->redirect("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/accountC", 302);
```

Для перехода на страничку «accountC».
Переход **работает**.
Но запись какая-то – не очень.
**1**. Я правильно написал?
**2**. Там еще был метод "*::base*", https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/URL#methods , дающий возможность получить базовый *ur*l, но у меня с его помощью получилось получить только «/» (правй слэш).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам необходимо осуществить перенаправление на адрес внутри текущего домена, вы можете использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
$this->redirect('/accountC', 302);
```

А в конфигурационном файле `system/config/url.php` добавьте домен сайта

```
return array(
    'trusted_hosts' => array(
        'sitedesigner',
    ),
);
```

При условии что sitedesigner -- домен вашего сайта.

Comment: да я уже пробывал, при такой записи у меня, летит ошибка "**Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Untrusted host sitedesigner. If you trust sitedesigner, add it to the trusted hosts in the `url` config file.**"

Comment: Ну собственно, суть указана в ошибке, добавьте домен своего сайта в файл конфигурации

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ

Comment: **СПАСИБО**,  создал файлик "*...\Endels1_72\home\SiteDesigner\www\application\config\url.php*", Все заработало. А по второму, вопросу. там можно получить "http ://sitedesigner" с помощью ::base?

Comment: так ПОДОЖДИТЕ, а если я сайт перенесу на удаленку, там название домена поменяется, я *url.php* тоже тогда должен **менять** получается?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю да, поскольку кохана будет требовать добавления домена в список доверенных в любом случае.

Comment: Установил на удаленку (домен поменялся), но *url.php* - менять почему-то **НЕ** пришлось, вот такие дела...